# Showing that a set defined by inequality is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Suppose we have a set $A$ defined as the set of all points $x$ such that $f(x) \geq 0$, for a continuous $f$ defined on the real line.

I'm using inverse image. $A = f^{-1}(A_0)$ for some $A_0$, which represents all the points $y =f(x) \geq 0$. Now I just need to show that $A_0$ is closed. I am not sure how to go about doing it though.

Take an arbitrary limit point $y_0$ of $A_0$, and we need to show that it is also in $A_0$, i.e. show that $y_0 \geq 0$.

That is where I get stuck, because my argument that $y_0$ must be nonnegative is a bit weak to me. Suppose that $y_0 < 0$; then, take the neighborhood $(y_0 - \delta, y_0 + \delta)$ such that $y_0 + \delta \leq 0$. Then, clearly this neighborhood contains no points in $A_0$, contradicting our assumption that $y_0$ was a limit point. I'm not sure if it's obvious that such a $\delta$ exists (it is to me?) and my proof kind of relies on that.

Comment: $A$ is a subset of the teals and what is the codomain of $f$?

Comment: maps from reals to reals @HennoBrandsma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but should set it up a bit more formally.

$A = \{x \mid f(x) \ge 0\}$. Take an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ with $x_n \in A$ for all $n$ which converges, say to $x$. Then $f(x_n) \ge 0$ for all $n$, by definition. We need to show that $x \in A$, ie $f(x) \ge 0$.

Suppose for a contradiction that $x < 0$. Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x + \delta < 0$. But you know, by definition of continuity*, that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$. So there exists $N$ such that $|f(x_n) - f(x)| < \delta$ for all $n \ge N$. In particular,
$$ f(y_x) \le \delta + f(x) < 0. $$
This contradicts the fact that $x_N \in A$.

*There are multiple equivalent definitions of continuity. Another is that $|f(x) - f(y)|$ is small whenever $|x - y|$ is small. You can adjust the proof to use this definition, since $y_n$ gets close to $y_\infty$.

Comment: Thank you - I've got two comments. When you wrote $f(y_n) \geq 0$ I thought $y_n = f(x_n)$ for some $x_n$ by definition of $A_0$, so what would be the meaning of $f(y_n)$?

Second comment is that in my book at least (Strichartz) we have a definition for limit point as "every neighborhood of limit point has a point in the set $A_0$". So I was trying to use that definition to prove it, and then not using anything about sequences - is that still not formal?

Comment: I guess a third comment is that I allowed $y_0 + \delta \leq 0$, because if $y_0 + \delta = 0$, then we would have the neighborhood $(y_0 - \delta, 0)$ and would still be unable to find any $y_n \geq 0$ in there

Comment: Sorry for not reading your question carefully enough and for the slow reply---for the second, I was on holiday! You can mostly just replace "$y_n$" by "$x_n$" and it's kinda ok. I rewrote it anyway. You should try to prove the equivalence between the definition of "closed" that you had and the sequence version. Namely, a set is clsoed if and only if every convergence sequence in the set has its limit point in the set. It's really important to understand how to use both!

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $[0, \infty)$ is closed, you have to prove that $[0, \infty)^c = (-\infty, 0)$ is open. But this is easy. Suppose $x_0 \in (-\infty, 0)$. Pick $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough so that $x_0 + \varepsilon < 0$, e.g. $\varepsilon = \frac{0 - x_0}{2}$. Then $(x_0 - \varepsilon, x_0 + \varepsilon) \subset (-\infty, 0)$.

Comment: Or $(-\infty, 0) = \bigcup_{n} (-n,0)$ a union of open intervals/balls , so open. And then your set is just $f^{-1}[[0,\infty)]$ so closed.